# Most reliable way of exiting out of a function on a failed try

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, error-handling, return

What is the best way to except out of ALL potential errors?

```
## Try to...
try:
    ## Print
    print "hi"
## On failure to get data
except Exception:
    ## Exit out of current function
    return
```

or

```
## Try to...
try:
    ## Print
    print "hi"
## On failure to get data
except:
    ## Exit out of current function
    return
```

or are there better ways?

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Comment: `except:` is shorthand for `except BaseException:`. See the [class heirarchy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) for what that includes.

Comment: Generally, the best way is to not do that. If you can't handle an exception (and you probably can't handle *everything*), let it propagate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, always catch specific errors you know will occur. Especially if you catch everything, (That is, `except:`) you will catch `KeyboardInterrupt` and make your program not be stoppable by `Ctrl+C`; `SystemExit` that is used to kill a thread, and so forth... While catching `Exception` is slightly better, it will still lose too much context; the exceptional condition that occurs might be other than you *expected*. Thus always catch `IOError`, `ValueError`, `TypeError` and so forth, by their names.

**Update**

There is 1 case where you want to use except Exception; at a top level of a program, or an action where you want to make sure that the whole program does not crash due to an uncaught Exception.

Answer (score 3):

Never use a bare `except:`. If you do, you'll wind up catching things like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt`, which are not intended to be caught in most code.

Ideally, you should try to be as specific as possible - for example, catching `IOError` for a failing `print`. If you can't predict exactly what exceptions you're concerned about, then at the very least you should use `except Exception` to avoid the aforementioned problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. I'll award the answer to Antii Haapala as he was slightly faster and well his rep is no where near as high as yours :P Thank you though